# Serial.write(5) not able to send decimal?

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-monitor

I am trying, as a test to Serial.write the int value: 5, to serial monitor, and if received, i want to print the the text "SUCCESS!" to the serial monitor.

But when writing `Serial.write((int)5);` All i get in the serial monitor is:
[image]

I have tried using Serial.println(5); which works fine, but then i am not able to read it.

My code:

```
enum read_states {
  Modtag_Adresse, 
  Modtag_Bit_Position_I_Adresse, 
  Modtag_Bit_Position_Vaerdi
};

enum read_states state;

void setup() {
  state = Modtag_Adresse;
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if(state == Modtag_Adresse) {
    Serial.write((int)5);
    delay(1000);

    if(Serial.available() > 0) {
      int serialReceived = Serial.read();

      if(serialReceived >= 0) {
          // Receive value 5
        Serial.print("SUCCESS!!");
      }
    }
  }

  else if(state == Modtag_Bit_Position_I_Adresse) {
    //
  }

  else if(state == Modtag_Bit_Position_Vaerdi) {
    //
  }

  else {
    // Failure.
  }
}
```

Comment: because that sends 5, not the ASCII code for 5 (which is 53). Try Serial.print(5)

Comment: Thank you, as i wrote, i have tried with Serial.print(5), and it works, but then i cant seem to read it in my "if(serialReceived >= 0) {"

Comment: Why do you think you can't read it?

Comment: I would have tought it is because we are not using Serial.write, should Serial.read not read inputs from the serial?

Comment: Serial.read should read inputs from serial. By the way, what is the serial connected to? It seems like it's connected to your computer because you are seeing it in the serial monitor? You know that Serial.read reads data the other end of the connection has sent, right? It doesn't read data the Arduino sent - unless you connected it in a loop - because that would be pointless.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. But i wanted to send values from Hercules, to begin with, i just wanted to test with sending static inputs from the program itself. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Serial.write(5)` sends the byte 5 to the computer. It appears as a square, because it's not an ASCII code of a letter or number or symbol.

`Serial.print(5)` sends the ASCII code for 5 (which is 53).

The reason you can't read what you wrote is because `Serial.write` sends data to the computer and `Serial.read` returns data received from the computer. If it read data from the Arduino program, it would be pointless because you don't need to use serial for that.